# Trying to understand DecimalFormat scientific notation formatting

Tags: java, formatting, scientific-notation

I noticed some behaviour with Java's `DecimalFormat` class that I don't quite understand. Specifically to do with the decimal point in scientific notation.

Refer to this test program (I'm still on Java 6 btw):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalFormatTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatValue("##0.0E0", 34627.2));   // (A) 34.63E3
        System.out.println(formatValue("##0.00E0", 346272.2)); // (B) 346.3E3
        System.out.println(formatValue("##0.0E0", 300000));    // (C) 300E3
    }

    private static String formatValue(String pattern, double value) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        return decimalFormat.format(value);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

*(1) Why does (A) have 2 digits after the decimal point when my pattern is asking for a single digit?*

With a similar pattern ("##0.0E+0") and the same value, Excel produces the expected "34.6E+3".

I can get DecimalFormat to produce the same output if I do `decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0)`, which confuses me even more.

Contrast this with (B), which has 346272.2 as its input instead of 34627.2, and this one produces the expected number of fractional digits.

---

*(2) For (C), why did the single digit after the decimal point in my pattern get ignored?*

Why is the output not "300.0E3" instead? This is what Excel produces.

I'm half-suspecting that the answer to this is similar to question 1.

---

*(3) Lastly, an optional bonus question, does anyone know if there's a formatter/tool that more faithfully matches the functionality of Excel's `TEXT()` function?*

I'm hoping to find a way to mimic that behaviour, or get as close as possible, without having to write my own formatter.

Thanks in advance.